# run commands in linux shell using batch file

Tags: android, linux, shell, batch-file

I need to be able to run the following commands on a rooted Android phone connected to my PC:

```
su
mount -o rw,remount /system
chmod 777 /system/app/
exit
exit
```

And then I need to execute the following command on my PC:

```
adb push ..\bin\MyApp_signed.apk /system/app/
```

And finally, I need to do some clean up and reboot the phone:

```
su
chmod 755 /system/app/
reboot
exit
exit
```

How can I create a windows batch file so that those shell commands are passed to the android shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`adb shell <command>` allows you to run a shell command on the device from your computer.  If your `su` command supports the `-c` option, you can do this:

```
adb shell su -c "mount -o rw,remount /system"
adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /system/app/"

adb push ..\bin\MyApp_signed.apk /system/app/

adb shell su -c "chmod 755 /system/app/"
adb shell su -c reboot
```

If your `su` command doesn't support commands, you could make a script to leave on the device that bundles the device side of it.